# Download untracked files from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, gitignore

Basically there is an app developed by someone else whom I can't contact. I have to download the uploads folder which contains all the images of product so that my local system looks good. Not to mention the folder is gitignored and all image assets are untracked. Is there any way I can download them?

Answer (score 1):

The assets won't be on Heroku. You can't store uploads on Heroku - well you can but they would be lost when the application restarts or is scaled.

Chances are they are on Amazon S3 - have a look around in your code to see if there is any mention of credentials.

Comment: Application code is written to store it in /public/uploads, and in local environment they are referenced from /public/uploads, I can't find any amazon or ec2 configuration in whole app (gone through most of the stuff in config folder, did a global search for specific strings like amazon, ec2, s3). But these images are stored in s3 in heroku. Heroku does that automatically I guess (URL structure at heroku: app-name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/:id/:filename.jpg)